# Problem while applying trigonometric functions in QGIS 3.1

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator

Using the Trigonomteric functions in the QGIS 3.1 field calculator gives me unexpected output. For example `sin(180)` produces the output `-0.8011526357338304` instead 0.

What is the reason for this?

How do I achieve expected result using degree as input?

Comment: you need to convert your input to radians mulitply by pi/180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigonometric functions in QGIS expressions (`sin`, `cos`, `tan`) expect the input angle to be specified in radians.

You can convert your input to radians using the `radians` function, so your example would look like this:

```
sin(radians(180))
```